# Get array data from Redis - How to store and retrieve

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, redis

I've been reading up on redis and haven't been able to decide how to save and retrieve my data. Below is a function that fetches data from MySQL DB;

```
// Initiate redis instance
$redis = new Redis();

// Connect to elasticache instance
$redis->connect('redis-001.xxx.0001.euxw1.cache.amazonaws.com', 6379);

    function getMenu ($connection) {
    $data = array();
    $restaurant_id = $_POST['restID'];

    try {

     if($redis->exists('menu_uniqueID')) {
        // read from redis and into 2D array
        $data['data'][$row['cat_name']][] = $redis->get('menu_uniqueID');
        $data['success'] = true;
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit;
     } else {

        // Menu category & items query
        // array to store results
        $query = "SELECT
    cat.name AS cat_name,
    i.id AS item_id,
    i.name AS name,
    i.description AS description,
    i.price AS price
FROM menu_categories AS cat
INNER JOIN menu_items AS i
    ON cat.id = i.cat_id
WHERE i.rest_id = $restaurant_id";

        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        if($result) {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                // read into 2D array
                $data['data'][$row['cat_name']][] = $row;
               // save into Redis
               $redis->set('menu_uniqueID', json_encode($row));
            }
        }

        $data['success'] = true;
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit;
       }
    } catch (Exception $e){
        $data = array();
        $data['success'] = false;
        $data['message'] = $e->getMessage();
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit;
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm retrieving a 2Dimensional Array and passing it back to my frontend (`AngularJS`) t consume and display using `ng-repeat`

I want the result from this query to be saved. Also you can see that I send data from my frontend (`$_POST['restID']`) which is parameter for searching.

So what i want to do is

First Time;

1. $query as usual
2. Save $query result in Redis with key `result_$_POST['restID']`

Second Time;

1. Check in redis if key `result_$_POST['restID']` exists
2. If it exists then JSON encode and pass back to frontend

Thanks

Comment: redis is a key value store, so just save the json string, under the `$_POST['restID']` key. process:  check redis, if exists, echo the result, else do the SQL query, create the json string, save in redis then echo

Comment: How do I save it is what I'm after; `HASH`? `SET`? `LIST`? Any chance you can show some code please

Comment: well it looks like you are just using is as a cache, so just save the json string (as a string) - if you show the code you are using to access redis i can write an answer

Comment: Check my edit, setting and getting as `STRING` with `json_encode`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few issues, 1st `$redis` must be in scope of the funtion.
Next, you want to save and retrieve the whole json string:

```
function getMenu ($connection) {
    // Initiate redis instance
    $redis = new Redis();

    // Connect to elasticache instance
    $redis->connect('redis-001.xxx.0001.euxw1.cache.amazonaws.com', 6379);
    $restaurant_id = $_POST['restID'];

    //check for redis cached data
    if($redis->exists('menu_' . $restaurant_id)) {
        // read json string from redit
        $json = $redis->get('menu_' . $restaurant_id);
    }else{
        //if not in redis, do query
        $data = [];


        try {

            // Menu category & items query
            // array to store results
            $query = "...WHERE i.rest_id = $restaurant_id";

            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
            if($result) {
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    // read into 2D array
                    $data['data'][$row['cat_name']][] = $row;
                }
            }

            $data['success'] = true;
            //create json string
            $json =  json_encode($data);
            //save in redis for latter access
            //probably you want to set expiry here as well, in case values change
            $redis->set('menu_' . $restaurant_id, $json);

        } catch (Exception $e){
            $data = [];
            $data['success'] = false;
            $data['message'] = $e->getMessage();
            $json =  json_encode($data);
        }
    }
    //echo json
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo $json;
    exit;   
}
```

Comment: Just to confirm I don't need to `json_encode` the data retrieved from Redis correct?